# Syntastic not checking puppet files

Tags: vim, puppet, vim-plugin, syntastic, pathogen

I have installed the [Syntastic vim plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) using [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) and am attempting to have my puppet files validated using puppet and puppet link checker.

I can see errors and warning from puppet-lint, but in addition to that I would expect the puppet validation to run to highligh syntax errors. Would you know what might cause only puppet-lint to run?

FYI, I am trying to get this to work in gVim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar setup and the puppet-lint checker as well as the puppet run fine for me.

Issuing the `:SyntasticInfo` command for a `.pp` file gives me the following:

[image]

I am pretty sure that this just might be a case of the puppet executable not being on the path, and hence not available for the validation.

Comment: Yup, that was it!! I thought I had it on the path. Thanks!